# KVM - how to install guest on Hetzner / Debian 9?

Tags: debian, kvm

Did anyone install a kvm guest successfully on a Hetzner dedicated server?

I terribly fail:

My guest does not have internet during the installation process. It cannot download find the debian archive. I use the bridge configuration with additional ip addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Not via KVM, but if you use the control panel to initiate Rescue mode and log in as root, you can install image via their `installimage` script, documented here: https://wiki.hetzner.de/index.php/Installimage/en